# map.connect in routes.rb not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Instead of adding teams one-by-one, I'm trying to create a form to enter a bunch of comma-separated team names all at once.  In my routes.rb, I have

```
map.connect '/teams/massentry', :controller => 'teams', :action => 'massentry'
map.resources :teams
```

In teams_controller.rb, I have

```
def massentry
  @team = Team.new
end
```

That's not what that will look like when I'm done.  I just stuck it in there so there would be something.  Finally, I have /views/teams/massentry.html.erb

```
<% form_tag({:controller => "teams", :action => "massentry"}, :method => 'get') do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:t, "CSV List of Teams" %>
    <%= text_area_tag(:t, "", :size => "24x6") %>
  </p>
  <p><%= submit_tag("Submit") %></p>
<% end %>
```

I don't know if that form is right and obviously don't have any of the logic written, but I just wanted to see what it looks like.  If I go to

```
http://localhost:3000/teams/massentry
```

It returns Couldn't find team with id=massentry.  It's executing the show method, but I thought if I put the map.connect before the resource line in routes.rb it would redirect.  Using rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails routes are evaluated [in the order they appear](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). So you can either leave it the way you just described (your custom route first) or you can do it in a [RESTful way](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) like @numbers1311407 said. Also, it makes more sense to use [:post instead of :get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778385/rails-post-put-get).

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
map.resources :teams, :collection => { :massentry => :get }
```

Comment: I get the same result replacing my two lines in routes.rb with the line above.  I also tried :post instead of :get.  The thing that shows what the server is doing starts with "Processing TeamsController#show", so it appears to be not getting the map line.